# How to Join tables to get the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having data like below

Table1 data:

```
Attr1    Attr2
36 L
37 L
38 L
39 L
40 L
41 L
42 L
43 L
44 L
46 L
48 L
50 L
52 L
54 L
56 L
58 L
60 L
62 L
36 P
37 P
38 P
39 P
40 P
41 P
42 P
43 P
44 P
46 P
48 P
50 P
52 P
54 P
56 P
58 P
60 P
62 P
36 PL
37 PL
38 PL
39 PL
40 PL
41 PL
42 PL
43 PL
44 PL
46 PL
48 PL
50 PL
52 PL
54 PL
56 PL
58 PL
60 PL
62 PL
36 PS
37 PS
38 PS
39 PS
40 PS
41 PS
42 PS
43 PS
44 PS
46 PS
48 PS
50 PS
52 PS
54 PS
56 PS
58 PS
60 PS
62 PS
36 R
37 R
38 R
39 R
40 R
41 R
42 R
43 R
44 R
46 R
48 R
50 R
52 R
54 R
56 R
58 R
60 R
62 R
36 S
37 S
38 S
39 S
40 S
41 S
42 S
43 S
44 S
46 S
48 S
50 S
52 S
54 S
56 S
58 S
60 S
62 S
36 XL
37 XL
38 XL
39 XL
40 XL
41 XL
42 XL
43 XL
44 XL
46 XL
48 XL
50 XL
52 XL
54 XL
56 XL
58 XL
60 XL
62 XL
```

And table2 like below:

```
ItemCode          Attr1     Attr2
ITEM-000001 43 S
ITEM-000001 52 L
ITEM-000006 42 R
ITEM-000006 44 R
ITEM-000009 56 R
```

there will be more items in table2.

How i can get output in which i will get the all rows of table1 who are having same 'Attr2'
say for example 'ITEM-000001' having two Attr2 - 'S' & 'L' so it will display as shown below:

```
Attr1    Attr2       ItemCode
    36 L           ITEM-000001
    37 L           ITEM-000001
    38 L           ITEM-000001
    39 L           ITEM-000001
    40 L           ITEM-000001
    41 L           ITEM-000001
    42 L           ITEM-000001
    43 L           ITEM-000001
    44 L
    46 L
    48 L
    50 L
    52 L
    54 L
    56 L
    58 L
    60 L
    62 L           ITEM-000001
    36 S           ITEM-000001
    37 S
    38 S
    39 S
    40 S
    41 S
    42 S
    43 S
    44 S
    46 S
    48 S
    50 S
    52 S
    54 S           ITEM-000001
    56 S           ITEM-000001
    58 S           ITEM-000001
    60 S           ITEM-000001
    62 S           ITEM-000001
```

Comment: I noticed that your results are in sorted order, but you didn't specify any ordering in your question. Is the order relevant?

Comment: No, orderning is not required

Comment: Please check if my updated answer is what you need.

Comment: yes, it will work if i will be having only 'S' & 'L' for all Items but it is not the case :(

Comment: It is showing 2 recors for 'S' & 'L' only.

Comment: @Om: I think nobody here understands your question at all. Could you a) post less data so that it fits on a page. b) Post the *exact* output you want for this data (i.e. don't write 'and so on...' or 'you get the picture' or anything like that). c) Make sure the values and column names line up correctly. d) Reword your question more carefully - avoid using ambiguous terms and phrases.

Comment: Could someone with editing priv's please reformat the tables. It took me a while to realize that `ITEM-000001 43 S` actually was three columns and not the contents of the first column.

Comment: Also: Use could you use real table and column names instead of things like Attr1 and Attr2. I think it would make things so much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All thank you for all your efforts & time for my question, here is the query which will give me the expected result. Thank you very much to all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ItemCode, T1.Attr1, T2.Attr2
FROM  
    (
       SELECT Attr1
       FROM Table1
    ) AS T1

    CROSS JOIN

    ( 
       SELECT ItemCode, Attr2
       FROM Table2
    ) AS T2
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**

Reading your query, I guess I finally know what you want:

Get all DISTINCT `ItemCode` and `Attr2` from `Table2`, and join all DISTINCT `Attr1` from `Table1`. I still can not see that from your provided samples...

You could reduce your query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ItemCode, T1.Attr1, T2.Attr2
FROM
  Table1 T1
  CROSS JOIN Table2 T2
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

I guess that performance could be improved by:

```
SELECT T2.ItemCode, T1.Attr1, T2.Attr2
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT Attr1
    FROM Table1
  ) T1
  CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT ItemCode, Attr2
    FROM Table2
  ) T2
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

---

**Original post:**

You can do this using a `LEFT JOIN`. This will return all rows of `Table1` and join rows of `Table2` where the condition matches. Columns of `Table2` are `NULL`, if no row is matched.

```
SELECT t1.Attr1, t1.Attr2, t2.ItemCode
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON ( t2.Attr1 = t1.Attr1 AND t2.Attr2 = t1.Attr2 )
WHERE t1.Attr2 IN ( 'S', 'L' )
```

Comment: It's not giving expected result it is mixing other attributes too for same item.

ItemCode Attribute1 Attribute2
NULL 62 L
NULL 62 P
NULL 62 PL
NULL 62 PS
NULL 62 R
NULL 62 S
NULL 62 XL
ITEM-000001 43 L
ITEM-000001 52 L
ITEM-000001 43 P
ITEM-000001 52 P
ITEM-000001 43 PL
ITEM-000001 52 PL
ITEM-000001 43 PS

Comment: Please see the the expected result which is having only 'S' & 'L' as Attr2 for ITEM-000001.

Answer (score 2):

I think finally I understand your question. First let me describe what I think you want in my own words, to see if I understand correctly your requirements.

You want to make a query for a specific item code. Table1 shows all (Attr1, Attr2) combinations that are possible, and Table2 shows which are available for the specific item code. You want to return rows for those Attr2 that are available for your item code, and for each (Attr1, Attr2) pair show whether or not the item code is available for this pair.

I think this query does what you want:

```
SELECT T1.Attr1, T1.Attr2, T2_2.ItemCode
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2_1
ON T1.Attr2 = T2_1.Attr2
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2_2
ON T1.Attr1 = T2_2.Attr1 AND T1.Attr2 = T2_2.Attr2
WHERE T2_1.ItemCode = 'ITEM-000001'
```

For your (incomplete) test data the result is:

```
36, 'L', ''
37, 'L', ''
38, 'L', ''
39, 'L', ''
40, 'L', ''
41, 'L', ''
42, 'L', ''
43, 'L', ''
44, 'L', ''
46, 'L', ''
48, 'L', ''
50, 'L', ''
52, 'L', 'ITEM-000001'
54, 'L', ''
56, 'L', ''
58, 'L', ''
60, 'L', ''
62, 'L', ''
36, 'S', ''
37, 'S', ''
38, 'S', ''
39, 'S', ''
40, 'S', ''
41, 'S', ''
42, 'S', ''
43, 'S', 'ITEM-000001'
44, 'S', ''
46, 'S', ''
48, 'S', ''
50, 'S', ''
52, 'S', ''
54, 'S', ''
56, 'S', ''
58, 'S', ''
60, 'S', ''
62, 'S', ''
```

I have have misunderstood something, please let me know.

Comment: 'Item-000001' is an ItemCode and I don't think he is looking to filter it, but just using it as an example.

Comment: @norlando: No, I think he *does* want to restrict to a specific item code. His provided example result set seems quite explicit about that - only one item code appears. I've completely rewritten my answer based on my new understanding of the question.

Comment: I think I see what your saying now. Grab all of the records with 'S' and 'L' and only grab the ItemCode if it contains 'ITEM-000001', else just leave it null.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to grab all records from table 1 that have an ItemCode of a specific value, like 'Item-000001'.

If that's the case the code below should do what you want, just replace the 'Item-000001' with what ever value you looking for.  Also, if you are looking for only records that have an Attr2 of 'S' or 'L' then you'll need the second part of the where clause.

```
SELECT T1.Attr1, T1.Attr2, T2.ItemCode
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Attr1 = T2.Attr1 AND T1.Attr2 = T2.Attr2
WHERE T2.ItemCode = 'Item-000001' AND T2.Attr2 IN ('S', 'L')
```